# Переменные из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Как вытащить переменные из массива?

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => getPlayerInfo
                    [success] => 0
                )
            [returnset] => Array
                (
                    [error] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => GameRequest does not exist with token=token
                                )
                        )

                    [errorCode] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 2000
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема?

Comment: Не получается вытащить значения к примеру  [errorCode] [value] => 2000, не могу получить значение 2000 итд

Comment: я добавил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: если ответ вам помог, нажмите зеленую галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = [
    'result' => [
        '@attributes' => ['name' => 'getPlayerInfo', 'success' => 0],
        'returnset' => [
            'error' => [
                '@attributes' => ['value' => 'GameRequest does not exist with token=token']
            ],
            'errorCode' => [
                '@attributes' => ['value' => 2000]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

echo $array['result']['returnset']['errorCode']['@attributes']['value']; // 2000
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Совсем устал!